# Unable to connect to GCM using agsXMPP (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, agsxmpp

I've been trying for about a day to just open an XMPP connection to GCM using the agsXMPP library.  I'm new to the library and XMPP in general so its entirely possible i'm making a silly mistake.  The only other thing that I know could be the problem is that my project has not yet been whitelisted by google, but I had read elsewhere that you should still be able to connect initially.  My code is as follows:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] argus)
    {

        XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
        xmpp.UseSSL = true;
        xmpp.UseStartTLS = false;
        xmpp.Server = "gcm.googleapis.com";
        xmpp.ConnectServer = "gcm.googleapis.com";
        xmpp.Port = 5235;
        xmpp.Password = "My Api Key";
        xmpp.Username = "My Project Id";
        xmpp.OnAuthError += OnAuthError;
        xmpp.OnError += OnError;
        xmpp.OnSocketError += new ErrorHandler(objXmpp_OnSocketError);

        xmpp.Open();

        // Just to keep the app open
        while (true) 
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

    static void objXmpp_OnSocketError(object sender, Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }

    static void OnAuthError(object sender, agsXMPP.Xml.Dom.Element e)
    {
        return;
    }

    static void OnError(object sender, Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }




}
```

What ends up happening is that i hit the SocketError with the following error:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.20.188:5235

Is this because I have yet to be whitelisted, or is there more that I can do with agsXMPP settings? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Project was whitelisted, unfortunately I am still getting the same error. So that rules that out as a cause.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this:  I figured it out. All of the code above will work just fine to connect to GCM. My companies corporate firewall was blocking the port.  In retrospect I should have checked this sooner.